# The numerical aperture of optic fibre and angle of incidence

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, fiber-optics, optical-materials

**First**
My college book contains the following passage:

> the angle of incidence (relative to the fibre axis ) can't be too large else the ray would be refracting on the core\cladding boundary and transmitted outside the fiber and a very small percentage passes.

Here's how I reasoned and I'd like to be corrected. The geometry I imagined was as follows:

- light falls with a very large angle $\alpha$ from air,
- light is refracted with angle $\theta$, $\theta$ < $\alpha$,
- light falls on cladding with large angle $\beta$ where: $ \alpha > \beta $ and $\beta > \theta c$ of the material of the cladding,
- light is simply totally internally reflected.

**Second**

I looked it up and found numerical aperture and acceptance angle articles but I'd like to be cleared out on the first matter first.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article on [total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection)?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct for the most part - except the third bullet:
α>β is not always valid.

Consider the following for example:
α = 50 deg & 
refractive index of core = 1.5. 
By Snell's law, θ = 31 and this leads to a β of 59 (90-31). So α(50) < β (59).

Typically, as α increases, θ will also increase, thereby bringing down β leading to "light leaking out through the cladding".
Hope it helps.

Comment: i checked and youre right , it did help
i will rewrite the question with a correction later